# Hyphen in the host name is getting lost on redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, asp.net-core-identity

I use AuthenticationProperties to expire the user session in based on the ExpiresUtc value. The session times out fine but the URL loses the hyphens on the host name when redirect happens.

Current page when session times-out redirect happens from:

for eg:
https://web-beta-test.chocolate.com/Search
to
https://webbetatest.chocolate.com/?ReturnUrl=%2FSearch

The hyphen is lost and therefore the server cannot find the page. localhost works fine on redirect to get me to the login page, because there are no hyphens involved.

What do I fix? Tips please

```
 try
            {
                var principal = await CreatePrincipal(userTicket.LoginName, userTicket, null);
                var context = _accessor.HttpContext;
                await context.SignInAsync(principal, GetAuthProperties());
                context.User = principal;
                return true;
            }
```

```
private AuthenticationProperties GetAuthProperties()
        {

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(SessionTime),
                // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
                // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
                // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

                IsPersistent = false,
                // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
                // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
                // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
                // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.

                IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now
                // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

            };
```

```
var principal = await CreatePrincipal(userTicket.LoginName, userTicket, null);
 var context = _accessor.HttpContext;
 await context.SignInAsync(principal, GetAuthProperties()); context.User = principal;
```

Comment: Where is the code that does the redirect.

Comment: Updated the question with code. I understand that once time expires (the one set in ExpiresUtc) the user gets automatically redirected to the Root page - where I redirect the user to the login page. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have no idea.  Are you using Core/Non-Core, asp.net-identity, web pages, razor pages?  It looks like it might be Core-Identity.

Comment: You are correct - .net core identity to expire user session

Comment: Are you using CookieAuthenticationOptions or IdentityOptions?  (What version of Core ? 1.x 2.x or 3.x) ?

Comment: updated the question with more code -  I am making use AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions  to manage the logged-in user session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this situation with lost hyphens - there is nothing wrong with the Authentication - the issue was with the load-balancer. It had to be corrected to allow the hyphens when the redirect occurs.